# ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler installing get-pip.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm getting this error when I try to install pip2.7. 
I have python 2.7 as my default already, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this.

OS: CentOS 6.5

OpenSSL has been installed already.
I followed this guide to install Python 2.7:
http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

```
[root@myservername arandomfolder]# python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 17474, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 17466, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 17406, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpXq2wUP/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpXq2wUP/pip.zip/pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpXq2wUP/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpXq2wUP/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I'm using Centos 6.5
I have installed Python 2.7 and it also comes with Python2.6 pre-installed
I have installed OpenSSL as well.

Comment: I was following this guide to install Python2.7
http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

Comment: is python referring to python 2.6 or 2.7?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Its referring to Python 2.7 

# which python
alias python='/usr/local/bin/python2.7'
        /usr/local/bin/python2.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler using PIP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-using-pip)

Answer (score 4):

You have a Python without SSL support compiled. Unfortunately, `get-pip` appears to *require* SSL support.

If you are using a Linux distribution, make sure OpenSSL is installed, including the headers when compiling Python from source.

Comment: I was going to give the same answer but was waiting to actually find out what os the OP is using.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Not Windows, obviously. Mac OS X comes with a Python that includes OpenSSL support, and compiling one will pick up the headers properly. So it is either a BSD or a Linux distro.

Comment: I understand that but there are different packages for different linux distributions.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: sure, and if and when the OP asks for help with that we can add that info.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  
I'm using Centos 6.5 I have installed Python 2.7 and it also comes with Python2.6 pre-installed I have installed OpenSSL as well.

Comment: @Shiro You need to recompile python from source and reinstall the python again.

Answer (score 1):

So looks like i was missing the openssl-devel dependency
after I had installed that, i was able to install this.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue on a Centos 6.5 machine even though I had openssl and openssl-devel installed. I was also using the steps from the site:
http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

I removed python packages I had installed before: virtualenv, NetworkX, and pil:

```
pip uninstall virtualenv
pip uninstall NetworkX
pip uninstall pil
```

Then I compiled Python 2.7 again and no longer had this issue. After I followed the steps in the link below, I reinstalled the above packages using pip2.7:

```
pip2.7 install virtualenv
pip2.7 install NetworkX
pip2.7 install pil --allow-external pil --allow-unverified pil
```

Answer (score 1):

I have meet the same problem. I solved it by install `openssl-devel` and `reconfigure`, `make`, `make install python3`:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

then go to the `python3` directory:

```
./configure --with-zlib --with-openssl

make

make install
```