# Unable to install Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

While trying to make attempt of installing it i get following error. What am I missing?

```
Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package Flask-SQLAlchemy. 

The following command was executed:

packaging_tool.py install --build-dir /private/var/folders/4B/4Bd6e77uH-uNGxBS-xhds++++TI/-Tmp-/pycharm-packaging5175396548329498703.tmp Flask-SQLAlchemy

The error output of the command:

Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 54, in do_install
    import pip
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib import version
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/version.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import string_types
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
    from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

Comment: No on Py2.7 as you can also see in error

Comment: I know some modules are split in **urllib2** for Python3.

Comment: btw, have you got `ssl` module installed?

Comment: here is the [SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler) with similar situation, you may find something useful. Hints: `ssl`, `OpenSSL` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the SO question got several answers [Python ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler).

Which in general, check if you have `ssl` module, and `OpenSSL` header files installed.

Comment: it's true my SSL got broken and reinstalled. Should I install python again via Homebrew?

Comment: You shouldn't need to, are you under virtualenv?

Comment: No I am not. I reinstall Python with openssl and it worked now.