# ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler

Tags: python, openssl, pip

Just installed pip, but I cannot import it. OS is RedHat enterprise and I also have the latest openssl (compiled from source) installed.

```
$ easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 8.1.1
Adding pip 8.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to XXX/local/bin
Installing pip3.5 script to XXX/local/bin
Installing pip3 script to XXX/local/bin

Using XXX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
$ python          
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Apr 27 2016, 15:32:43) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "XXX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "XXX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "XXX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "XXX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "XXX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "XXX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
    from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

I know I have to configure my openssl in a way that it works with python (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-using-pip)). This is how I configured openssl before I compile it:

```
# openssl-1.0.2g 
./config --prefix=XXX/local \
        --openssldir=XXX/local/etc/ssl \
        --libdir=lib \
        shared \
        zlib-dynamic \
        -LXXX/local/lib \
        -IXXX/local/include
```

Python version is 2.7

Comment: Maybe helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-using-pip

Answer (score 0):

I was using Centos and facing this issue.

Best way to solve is:

```
yum install openssl openssl-devel -y 
yum install krb5-devel -y
```

try one of two options:

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib 
export CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include

  OR
```

recompile it