# Cannot install PIP on Raspbian

Tags: python, python-3.5, raspbian-wheezy

I can't get PIP running in my Raspberry (running in Wheezy).
After I always got this message:

```
~ $ pip3
/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py:80:
UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future
versions will fail here.   warnings.warn(msg) Traceback (most recent
call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in
load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in
load_entry_point
    return ep.load()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py",
line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/vcs/mercurial.py",
line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/download.py",
line 36, in <module>
    from pip.utils.ui import DownloadProgressBar, DownloadProgressSpinner   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/utils/ui.py",
line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, IncrementalBar   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py",
line 48
    empty_fill = u'∙'
                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I compiled Python3.5 and now try running the get-pip.py script. But this gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in
<module>
    main()   File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)   File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip   File "/tmp/tmprewy_1xt/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>   File
"/tmp/tmprewy_1xt/pip.zip/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module> 
File "/tmp/tmprewy_1xt/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>  
File "/tmp/tmprewy_1xt/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>  
File "/tmp/tmprewy_1xt/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line
14, in <module>   File
"/tmp/tmprewy_1xt/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in
<module> ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
```

OpenSSL is installed.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Python and pip are usually already installed on most linux OS, but you could use `apt-get` to install pip if you didn't have it

Comment: likely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-using-pip but I'm guessing you knew that if you know to tell us that you have OpenSSL installed.

Comment: [Related question from AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/581999/pip-raises-importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler) Probably holds your solution.

Comment: Yes. libssl-dev is installed and the newest version. I checked that and even re-compiled again.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: tried this already as well but when trying to install as advised there I get the message:
Unable to locate package libpython2.7-stdlib

Comment: Can you `import ssl` from python?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: No: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testSSL.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorted.
Apparently my Python 2.7 install was somewhat corrupted.
After I did `sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade` which - with some hick-ups - fixed the install.
After that I re-built the 3.5.1 binaries and pip3 works now fine.