# Error when installing Pandas on Solaris 10

Tags: pandas

Currently we are on Python 2.7.17, and we are getting the following error:

```
sbdsvrwm261# ./pip install pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "/opt/csw/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in <module>
    from urllib2 import (Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError,
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

If you require further information from me, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler using PIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688034/importerror-cannot-import-name-httpshandler-using-pip)

Comment: No, as these answers correlate to Linux users. However, it does narrow down the cause of the problem to something to do with the ssl module

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [officially supports Python ^3.5.3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#python-version-support).

Have you tried using virtualenv or docker to get Python 3.*?

Comment: Hello, no we are still getting errors even when installing on python 3.5.3